# jQuery syntax error, unrecognised expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

syntax error, unrecognised expression:  `#2015-11-30|1112|1`

I have an anchor tag with an Id of '2015-11-30|1112|1' that I would like to apply a class to. I am doing the same method for on a '' and this works, but I am getting syntax errors with the following. Can anyone explain the syntax error?

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tbl_calendar").on("click", "a", null, clickAppointment);
    });


function clickAppointment(eventData)
    {
        //Get the Id of the appointment that has been clicked:
        currentAppointment = $(this).attr('id');

        //alert('clicked' + '#'+currentAppointment)

        $('#'+currentAppointment).addClass('selected');
    }
```

Comment: What's the `null` doing there? Change it to `$("#tbl_calendar").on("click", "a", clickAppointment);`, if you're not passing data, no need to use that argument

Comment: Why not just `$(this).addClass('selected');`? You're trying to select an element with the same `id` as the clicked element. If an `id` is unique, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) for valid characters for IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the special chracters in your `id` using `\\`, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
console.log( $("#2015-11-30\\|1112\\|1").text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="2015-11-30|1112|1">Div text example</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your current code to work, you don't have to use that id selector since you already have the reference of the object inside the event function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tbl_calendar").on("click", "a", clickAppointment);

  function clickAppointment(eventData) {
    //"this" will have a reference to the clicked object
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
});
```

Not sure about your HTML, but considering something similar to the below one.

```
<ul id="tbl_calendar">
  <li>
    <a id="2015-11-30|1112|1">Click</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/gtytp1qc/)